# How to set block display of inline elements in shadow root

Tags: html, css, shadow-dom

I have a few `<p>` tag in shadow root,they are inline codes. When I tried to style them like **display:block** for each. And it failed. How to set them one item below other? Thanks. 
This is the code I have used:

```
polyfill-next-selector{content: '.card-header #phone';}
.card-header ::content #phone
{
  display:block;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}

polyfill-next-selector{content: '.card-header #building';}
.card-header ::content #building
{
  display:block;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}

polyfill-next-selector{content: '.card-header #office';}
.card-header ::content #office
{
  display:block;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}

polyfill-next-selector{content: '.card-header #skype';}
.card-header ::content #skype
{
  display:block;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}

polyfill-next-selector{content: '.card-header #computerName';}
.card-header ::content #computerName
{
  display:block;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}

polyfill-next-selector{content: '.card-header #businessMobile';}
.card-header ::content #businessMobile
{
  display:block;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}
</style>
<div class="card-header" layout horizontal center>
  <content select="img"></content>
  <content select="h2"></content>
  <content select="#phone"></content>
  <content select="#building"></content>
  <content select="#office" ></content>
  <content select="#skype" ></content>
  <content select="#computerName" ></content>
  <content select="#businessMobile" ></content>
</div>
<content></content>
```

Comment: Can we have your code please.

Comment: I've added the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to target nods distributed **inside** content tags, instead of ::content itself.

*They are logically not inside content nodes though, but css selectors understand it that way.*

So instead of

```
::content 
{
  display:block;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}
```

it should be

```
::content > p
{
  display:block;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dct1n6d2/) as well for the same.

Take a look on this nice [tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/#toc-style-disbtributed-nodes) on styling distributed nodes also, if you haven't already.